# Appium send_keys overwritting previous text

Tags: appium, sendkeys

I'm trying to input text into three textfields:

new_email = self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.test.test/register_email_email')
new_email.send_keys(new_user, "@test.com")

new_username = self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.test.test:id/register_email_username')
new_username.send_keys(new_user)

new_password = self.driver.find_element_by_id('com.test.test:id/register_email_password')
new_password.send_keys('password')

new_email enters properly, but when new_username gets focus, the app deletes the 'c' and 'm' from the previous textfield. So instead of the email field reading user100@test.com, it reads user100@test.o

I can't for the life of me figure out why it's deleting only two characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update to the latest Appium (1.3.4) as this behaviour is fixed now. Also make sure you're using the latest appium_lib gem too.

$ npm update -g appium

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
new_email.clear().send_keys(new_user, "@test.com")
new_username.clear().send_keys(new_user)
new_password.clear().send_keys('password')
```